# Bessel J function problem

Tags: special-functions

Let $\xi_{0k}$ be the k-th positive zero of $J_{0}$ Bessel function. Determine the coefficients $c_k$, so that

$1 = \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} c_kJ_0(\frac{x \xi_{0k}}{2})$.

I don't see what to do, is this solvable?

Comment: Here you're summing up an infinite amount of things and putting an equal sign next to it. This suggests some sort of convergence. What kind of convergence are you looking for? Almost everywhere? Pointwise? Uniform?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#E37  Formula 10.22.37

Comment: its in the bible of Bessel functions, namely, Watson's book https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions